# Complex differentiability

Tags: complex-analysis

Would the complex function sech(z) be holomorphic because cosh(z) defined by its power series is holomorphic? I am not sure why sech (z) is even (complex) differentiable everywhere since surely it is not a "flat map" and the "gradient" along a contour line ($=0$) and that along a perpendicular of a contour line ($\neq 0$) are different!
Please explain!

Also is there a effective way of telling whether a complex function is differentiable and/or holomorphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be holomorphic because $\cosh i\pi/2=0$ therefore ${\rm sech} ~ i\pi/2 =\infty$. It is meromorphic instead because the reciprocal of a nonzero holomorphic function ($\cosh$ in this case) is always meromorphic.

If a function is given by its power series, you can often calculate its radius of convergence: the radius of the greatest $0$-centered open disk where it converges, which is in this case the same as being holomorphic there.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence

Comment: Thanks, Tib! Is holomorphic the same as being analytic/

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functions_are_analytic

Comment: I read a note an it says intuitively holomorphic functions 'depend only z but not on $\bar{z} $', isn't sech $z$ such? Or perhaps because it's only intuitive explanation so it's not always literally true?

Answer (score 0):

$\text{sech } z=\frac2{e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)+e^{-x}(\cos y-i\sin y)}=\frac{\cosh x\cos y-i\sinh x\sin y}{\cosh^2x-\sin^2 y}=u+iv$, where $1\leq \cosh x\neq |\sin y|\leq 1,$ that is, $x\neq0$ or $y \neq k\pi+\frac\pi2 (k\in\mathbb{Z}),$ that is, $z\neq i(k\pi+\frac\pi2).$

$u_x=\frac{-\sinh x\cos y}{(\cosh^2x-\sin^2 y)^2}(\cosh^2x+\sin^2y),$
$v_y=\frac{\sinh x\cos y}{(\cosh^2x-\sin^2 y)^2}(\cosh^2x+\sin^2y),$
and so $u_x\neq v_y$. Since holomorphic at a point is 'holomorphic in a neighbourhood of the point', which requires that $u_x=v_y$ everywhere, $\text{sech } z$ is not holomorphic at any point of $\mathbb{C}$.

We can also use that $u_y=\frac{-\cosh x\sin y}{(\cosh^2x-\sin^2 y)^2}(\cosh^2x+\cos 2y),$
$v_x=\frac{-\cosh x\sin y}{(\cosh^2x-\sin^2 y)^2}(\cos^2y),$ and so $u_x\neq -v_y$.

*Hope my calculation is correct, can anyone verify that?*